# Confusion regarding Fourier transform of $t$.

Tags: fourier-transform, dirac-delta

This is the Fourier transform pair I use:
\begin{eqnarray}
X (\omega) &=& \int_{-\infty}^\infty x(t) e^{-j\omega t} dt,\\
x(t) &=& \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty X(\omega) e^{j\omega t} d\omega,
\end{eqnarray}
where, $\mathcal{F}\{x(t)\}=X(\omega)$.

And here are the properties of Fourier transform related to the problem I have:

1. Time differentiation: $\mathcal{F}\left\{\dfrac{d x(t)}{dt}\right\} = j\omega X(\omega)$
2. Frequency differentiation: $\mathcal{F}\left\{t\,x(t)\right\} = j\dfrac{d X(\omega)}{d\omega}$

Now, I want to calculate $\mathcal{F}\{t\}$.

Using the time differentiation property:
\begin{eqnarray}
&&x(t) = t\\
\implies &&x'(t) = 1\\
\implies &&\mathcal{F}\{x'(t)\} = \mathcal{F}\{1\}\\
\implies &&j\omega X(\omega) = 2\pi \delta(\omega) \\
\implies &&X(\omega) = \dfrac{2\pi}{j\omega } \delta(\omega)
\end{eqnarray}

i.e. $\mathcal{F}\{t\} = \dfrac{2\pi}{j\omega } \delta(\omega)$.

But apparently, this is an incorrect result!

The correct solution is achievable using the frequency differentiation property:
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\mathcal{F}\{1\} = 2\pi\delta(\omega)\\
\implies &&\mathcal{F}\{t\} = j \dfrac{d}{d\omega}\left( 2\pi\delta(\omega) \right)\\
\implies &&\mathcal{F}\{t\} = 2j\pi\delta'(\omega)
\end{eqnarray}

Can someone please explain why the first method is wrong and why the later one is the correct one? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, md2perpe is right.
I would add that you should always be careful with distributions that the product of two distributions is not in general well defined. $\delta_0(\omega)/\omega$ has no meaning for instance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solutions to the distribution equation $x\,u(x) = \delta(x)$ are $u(x) = -\delta'(x) + C\,\delta(x).$ So from $j\omega X(\omega) = 2\pi \delta(\omega)$ you get the solutions
$X(\omega) = 2\pi j\,\delta'(\omega) + C\,\delta(\omega).$ Now, since $t$ is an odd function, so must be its Fourier transform, which makes $C=0.$

Comment: So essentially, $\omega \delta'(\omega) = -\delta(\omega)$

Comment: @TDG. That's correct. That's because $\omega \delta(\omega) = 0$ and by product rule:
$$0 = (\omega \delta(\omega))' = \delta(\omega) + \omega \delta'(\omega).$$